# Shortcut to mute tabs in Safari

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, safari, shortcut

Is there any shortcut to mute one specific tab in Safari? Or to mute all except the current tab? Using only the MacBook keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create your own keyboard shortcut that toggles the menu bar commands under Window (otherwise you'll see that there are no keyboard shortcuts listed there).

Keyboard Settings - Shortcuts - App Shortcuts - "+" - Safari, Mute This Tab, (insert desired shortcut)

Repeat for "Mute Other Tab" and "Mute Other Tabs" (multiple "other" tabs open).

---

NOTE: Play/Pause button works for YouTube (pauses last video interacted played/paused), possibly other sites as well.

---

Right clicking the sound icon in the address bar will give you this functionality too, but requires the mouse.

Comment: Finally, the problem is solved after more than 2 years. Thank you!!